# Show that there exist no retraction from $\mathbb{RP}^n$ to $\mathbb{RP}^k$ if $n>k$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying this problem from Hatcher's algebraic topology book (4.2.1).
If $r:X\rightarrow A$ is retraction then I know that this induces injective map in the fundamental group level through inclusion $A\subset X$.
So from fundamental group I am not able to solve this problem. I don't know role of higher homotopy groups in retraction problems.
Could anyone please give me some hint?
Thanks.

Comment: If $X$ retracts to $A \subset X$, then the induced map $\pi_n(A) \to \pi_n(X)$ is injective. This is not a result that's in any way special to $H_n$ or $\pi_n$; all you use to show it is functoriality.

Comment: @MikeMiller you are right...

Comment: @MikeMiller I think I got it.I need to use covering projection map from $S^n$ to$RP^n$ induces isomorphism on $\pi_n$. for n>1...now considering $\pi_k$ we will get contradiction...right @mike?